# Dynamic programming for allocating topics to lectures

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, recursion, theory, analysis

I have been working so hard on trying to define a recursive function to find out the solution of a dynamic programming problem. The problem is the following:

We want to teach a course and must cover n topics. The length of each lecture is `L` minutes. The topics require `t1,t2,...,tn ( 1 ≤ ti ≤ L)` minutes each. For each topic, you must decide in which lecture it should be covered. The topics can't be divided and have to be covered sequentially.

There is a dissatisfaction formula (DI) too, we can have free time in a particular lecture (no topics at time t) but this is going to affect or benefit the DI overall value.

I need to minimize the number of lectures; in case of more than one way of allocating the topics I will need to minimize the DI too.

I was thinking about a recursive function like this to solve the problem:

> M(j) = max {M(j-1) + t[j] <= L}

But I don't think this is right. The thing is that I need to group in some way topics such that the sum of their times is less or equal to L and also build at least one lecture.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?  If the topics must all be covered and in the given order, then why isn't the optimal answer just to schedule topics 1,2,3,etc until you run out of time in the first lecture, then move onto the second?  There doesn't seem to be any need for dynamic programming at the moment?

Comment: The problem, I think, is with the dissatisfaction formula. If in lecture i there is 0 free time, the DI = 0, if free time is less than or equal to 10 then DI = -C (C is a natural number); and DI = (free time - 10)^2 otherwise. I don't know if I can prove that doing what you say I will always have the smallest DI for all the other possible allocations.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part!  In that case I think you want to solve for the subproblem of "min dissatisfaction after scheduling j topics" by expanding over the choice of the number of topics in the current lecture (and only considering choices that are consistent with a minimal number of lectures)